# How to update multiple a column based on corresponding column value for multiple rows in postgres sql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table.

```
--------------------------------
|id|po_unit_price|po_qty|amount|
--------------------------------
|1 | 10          | 2    |null  |
--------------------------------
|2 | 20          | 4    |null  |
--------------------------------
```

now I want to update amount for all the rows with a single query.
amount will be `po_unit_price * po_qty`

I tried a quite my self and also tried googling but could not get any success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please choose only one rdms please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can column names on both sides of the assignment operator:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    amount = po_unit_price * po_qty
```

Although, if `amount` should always be the product of `po_unit_price` and `po_qty`, you should consider not keeping it as a column at all, and instead query it when you need it:

```sql
SELECT po_unit_price, po_qty, po_unit_price * po_qty AS amount
FROM   mytable
```